# Signification de « Si on sait pas, on va pas »

Tags: expressions

Ma grand-mère raconte souvent une histoire de la première fois qu'elle est venue à Bruxelles. Elle était perdue, et elle a demandé le bon chemin à un monsieur dans la rue. Apparemment, il l'a regardée et a répondu, « Madame, si on sait pas, on va pas. »

À part d'être une réponse pas très sympa, est-ce que quelqu'un a une idée de ce que le monsieur voulait dire par cette phrase bizarre ?

Comment: Décidément, demander son chemin dans les capitales francophones serait périlleux ? https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42734/write-a-dialogue-in-french7-8-simple-dialogues-dialogue-for-3-people

Comment: Sans doute inspiré de "Quand on sait pas on se tait"

Answer (score 2):

Pas très sympa en effet.

Je ne connaissais pas cette expression mais elle signifie tout simplement que si l'on ne connait pas le chemin pour aller a un endroit, on ne doit pas aller à cet endroit.

Donc je suis d'accord avec toi: pas très sympa comme réponse.